# How to ignore vertex failed error in hive

Tags: json, hive

I have been getting "`vertex failed`" error while inserting from a hive table (which have JSON data in it). I assume that the data in the table might be corrupted . I want to ignore the error if it occurs . How can I ignore that in hive?

Comment: Are you using Tez engine??

Comment: Yes , I have tried MR too , but I have been getting the same vertex failed issues. I want to ignore the error this time , is there a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I've personally faced this issue with TEZ engine, especially when dealing with huge data, with aggregation while (with distinct most probably).

When i re-run the same query by changing the execution engine to MR, it worked for me

```
SET hive. execution.engine=MR;
```

If you're using distinct anywhere in the query, just check removing it, check if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: I am not using distinct for this . Thanks for the info

Comment: Could you please post your query here